# Administrate gem not installed properly, throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, administrate

Tried to install Administrate, and already hit the bump.

Dubbing my beg for help from GitHub:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/2357

trying to run `rails g administrate:install` and got this:

```
route namespace :admin do
              resources :users
              resources :doctors
          
              root to: "users#index"
            end

WARNING: Unable to generate a dashboard for ActionMailbox::InboundEmail.
- Administrate does not yet support namespaced models.
- It is not connected to a database table.
Make sure your database migrations are up to date.
WARNING: Unable to generate a dashboard for ActiveStorage::Attachment.
- Administrate does not yet support namespaced models.
- It is not connected to a database table.
Make sure your database migrations are up to date.
WARNING: Unable to generate a dashboard for ActiveStorage::Blob.
- Administrate does not yet support namespaced models.
- It is not connected to a database table.
Make sure your database migrations are up to date.
WARNING: Unable to generate a dashboard for ActiveStorage::VariantRecord.
- Administrate does not yet support namespaced models.
- It is not connected to a database table.
Make sure your database migrations are up to date.
WARNING: Unable to generate a dashboard for ActionText::RichText.
- Administrate does not yet support namespaced models.
- It is not connected to a database table.
Make sure your database migrations are up to date.
WARNING: Unable to generate a dashboard for ActionText::EncryptedRichText.
- Administrate does not yet support namespaced models.
- It is not connected to a database table.
Make sure your database migrations are up to date.
create app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/administrate-0.18.0/lib/administrate/namespace.rb:9:in block in resources': uninitialized constant Administrate::Namespace::Resource (NameError) from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/administrate-0.18.0/lib/administrate/namespace.rb:8:in map'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/administrate-0.18.0/lib/administrate/namespace.rb:8:in resources' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/administrate-0.18.0/lib/generators/administrate/install/install_generator.rb:57:in dashboard_resources'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/administrate-0.18.0/lib/generators/administrate/install/install_generator.rb:53:in singular_dashboard_resources' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/administrate-0.18.0/lib/generators/administrate/install/install_generator.rb:34:in run_dashboard_generators'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in invoke_command'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in block in invoke_all' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in each'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in map' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in invoke_all'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in dispatch' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in start'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/generators.rb:263:in invoke' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:26:in perform'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in invoke_command'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in dispatch' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in perform'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in invoke' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in 

'
from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' from /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require'
from bin/rails:4:in `'
```

Then I tried to `rails destroy administrate:install` to undo this and got:

```
>[WARNING] Could not load generator "generators/administrate/install/install_generator". Error: uninitialized constant Admin::Administrate.

/Users/curlybastard/clinic/clinicapp/clinicapp/app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb:8:in <module:Admin>' /Users/curlybastard/clinic/clinicapp/clinicapp/app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb:7:in 

'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in require' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in const_get'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in cget' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:169:in block in actual_eager_load_dir'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in block in ls' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in each'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in ls' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:164:in actual_eager_load_dir'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in block (2 levels) in eager_load' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in each'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in block in eager_load' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in synchronize'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in eager_load' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:297:in block in eager_load_all'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:295:in each' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:295:in eager_load_all'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/administrate-0.18.0/lib/generators/administrate/install/install_generator.rb:2:in <main>' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in require'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:44:in block (2 levels) in lookup' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in each'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in block in lookup' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in each'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in lookup' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/generators.rb:245:in find_by_namespace'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/generators.rb:261:in invoke' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/destroy/destroy_command.rb:24:in perform'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in invoke_command'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in dispatch' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in perform'
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in invoke' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in '
/Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require' /Users/curlybastard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in require'
bin/rails:4:in <main>' Could not find generator 'administrate:install'. Did you mean?  administrate:field Run bin/rails generate --help` for more options.<
```

checked dependencies - same result. Have no idea where to aim, and feeling really stuck.

Comment: Do you have namespaced models as the error message indicates? Also, why do you need to use the destroy task when you could just discard the changes from your current git state?

Comment: That's my first attempt to use this gem, (trying to replace ActiveAdmin, which was quite a pain, btw), and I'm still learning RoR in general, so I'm not quite sure what to answer.
About Git - just forget, tbh. Lesson learned, I guess.

Comment: Standard models in Rails are not namespaced, e.g., `User`. Namespaced models are nested, e.g., `SomeParentModule::User`. Do you have the latter?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so.

Comment: As a guess, I would say you have somehow seriously misconfigured your Rails application.

Comment: Problem was solved, full story on GitHub by link in head post.